# xmlrpc-c library cannot link

Tags: c, xml-rpc

I feel embarrassed to ask this, but I cannot link my small demo program to the xmlrpc-c libs. I know it should be obvious but I am stumped.

I have the same problem if I install the library via apt (Debian) or build/install from source (Debian or macOS).

```
xmlrpc.c:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to `xmlrpc_client_setup_global_const'
xmlrpc.c:(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `xmlrpc_client_create'
xmlrpc.c:(.text+0xf9): undefined reference to `xmlrpc_client_call2f'
xmlrpc.c:(.text+0x166): undefined reference to `xmlrpc_client_destroy'
xmlrpc.c:(.text+0x16b): undefined reference to `xmlrpc_client_teardown_global_const'
```

The command I used to compile link was
`gcc $(xmlrpc-c-config --libs --cflags client) xmlrpc.c`

The output from `xmlrpc-c-config` is

```
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu   -lxmlrpc  -lxmlrpc_xmlparse -lxmlrpc_xmltok -lxmlrpc_util 
-I/usr/include
```

This all looks good and the libraries are in the expected place.

I have tried the traditional remedy of repeating the library names on the command line e.g.

`gcc $(xmlrpc-c-config --cflags client) xmlrpc.c   $(xmlrpc-c-config --libs client) $(xmlrpc-c-config --libs client)`

but this has had no effect. I have also reviewed the answers in [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc), but that does not seem to fix anything.

I have no idea what to try next (I have googled for all I'm worth, but to no avail)

Comment: Try gcc $(xmlrpc-c-config --cflags client) xmlrpc.c $(xmlrpc-c-config --libs client)

changing the order of libraries

Comment: Thanks for this -- great suggestion. However it did not make any difference. I've updated the question to use your suggestion

Comment: Problem fixed with help from lib maintainer. I had the arguments to `xmlrpc-c-config` incorrect. The correct command is `gcc $(xmlrpc-c-config client --cflags --libs) xmlrpc.c -o xmlrpc`